# setValue template in template(double template)

Tags: c++, templates

function(need to help):

```
template <typename T>
void QueryMember(const std::string names, const std::string& table ,vector<T>& vec)
{
    try
    {
        boost::scoped_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt(con->createStatement());
        std::string sql;
        sql = FormatArgs("select %s from %s", names, table);

        boost::scoped_ptr< sql::ResultSet > res(stmt->executeQuery(sql));
        sql::ResultSetMetaData* res_meta = res->getMetaData();
        vector<std::string> vecStr;
        int col = res_meta->getColumnCount();
        while (res->next())
        {
            vecStr.clear();
            for (int i=1;i<=col;i++)
            {
                vecStr.push_back(res->getString(i));
            }
            T t;
           //how to set the value of t and then push_back?
            vec.push_back(t);
        }
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e)
    {
        std::cout << "QueryMember ERR: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

its like that set value in double template

here:

```
T t;
//how to set the value of t and then push_back?
vec.push_back(t);
```

I have tried with memcpy tempclass to got what I want ..

and the strcut like that(maybe all is string)

```
typedef struct tagTest
{
    std::string test1;
    std::string test2;
    std::string test3;

}TESTQUERY;
```

and that is what I using the function:

```
vector<TESTQUERY> vec;
QueryMember("*", "test", vec);
```

Comment: Your call to the function does not match the function definition you show.

Comment: Aside from that what you're trying to do (I think) needs [*specialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) or *overloading*. You can not "set the value of t" if you don't really know what `t` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to be able to pass any T value to the function (based on the example function call that you showed). To do this, you need to add an additional parameter:

```
void QueryMember(const std::string names, const std::string& table, const T& t)
```

Then, you just need to use this `t` instead is creating another variable later.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sry.T is a strcut.and i need to set the vaule with vector<T> in QueryMember